# MySql Select with auto incrementing column not existing in table

Tags: mysql, row-number

I would like to select from a table and include in this select a column that is not existing in the table and it is a integer auto - incrementing.

Like:

```
SELECT username, 'c' as C FROM users;
```

where c doesn't exist in the table, but should be integer and auto-increment.

Comment: If it doesn't exist in the table how can you *select* it from the table?

Comment: What makes you think this is possible? Why would it be? You can't select something that doesn't exist. If you want an auto-incrementing column, just add one.

Comment: I want like an index included in the select results

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT username, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
FROM users
CROSS JOIN (select @rank := 0) r
ORDER BY username
```

So

```
CROSS JOIN (select @rank := 0) r
```

inits a variable named `rank`. And

```
@rank := @rank + 1 as rank
```

increments the variable for every row.